# How can I add a bunch of labels to a C# form and then scroll the form vertically?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, scrollbars, ui-design

I have a form in C# (WinForm).  It looks like this:

> ---
>
> (LOGO)
>
> blank space for labels that I add
>   through code (I can fit 10 labels in
>   this space)
>
> (close button)
>
> ---

The blank space can hold about 10 labels.

I am stumped on how I would make this form scrollable if I want to add 20 labels?  If I add 20 labels via code, then the 11th label will overlap with my close button and the 12th+ label(s) will run off the end of the form.

How do I make just the blank space portion of my form scrollable where I am creating the labels?  I don't want to use a listbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all controls inside a panel and use scrollbar control.

[Understand .NET Scrollbars](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/understandingScrollbars.aspx)

Comment: Given the existence of the `AutoScroll` property on most of the container controls offered by WinForms, this is probably the worst possible idea, not to mention the most difficult.

Comment: With auto scroll the logo and the close button would also scroll. Not a good UI design by any standards.

Comment: Only if you placed the logo and close button *inside* of the panel. You could keep them outside, dock the panel control in between them, and only add the label controls to the panel.

Comment: Also with scrollbars you get freedom of positioning the controls. Both tablelayout and flowlayouts are quite constraint and hard to manage as the design gets complex.

Answer (score 4):

**You should try using either a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) as a container for your `Label` controls.**

A `TableLayoutPanel` will allow you a finer level of control over where your labels are positioned. Like an HTML table, you specify the exact cell position (using row and column coordinates) of each control.

By contrast, a `FlowLayoutPanel` will handle the positioning of its contents automatically, either in a vertical or horizontal layout configuration. The positioning is determined by the order in which you add the controls, allowing you to achieve a dynamic layout with a minimal amount of fuss.

Either will allow you to add your label controls to it at run-time and size itself appropriately. In order for layout panel to be scrollable, **make sure that you set its `AutoScroll` property to "True".**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a `FlowLayoutPanel` with `AutoScroll` set to true and `FlowDirection` set to `TopDown`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).

Add as many labels you need and enable AutoScroll on the FlowLayoutPanel.